# How can I tell what version of the .NET framework has this bug fix?

Tags: .net

I saw this issue on the github site for CoreCLR: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10320

It is closed. So my questions are, which version of the .NET framework would have this bug fix, and how should I go about figuring that out (in case I have the same question about other such issues in the future)?

Comment: `Milestone: 2.0.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreCLR is the repository for .NET Core, not the traditional .NET Framework. Based on the issue's "milestone", it looks like this fix was included in .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, there is no indication that it is fixed or even logged as a bug for the .NET Framework?

Comment: @Anssssss Right, I believe bugs in .NET Framework are tracked in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/61/net.html?type=idea) and the release notes are in [the `Microsoft/dotnet` repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/tree/master/releases).

Comment: I couldn't see any issue at the Developer Community site or in the release notes. It is too bad that there isn't more communication between the projects. I entered a bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/464339/memory-leak-when-waitany-on-the-same-task-keeps-ti.html

Comment: Just to close the loop on this in case anyone was curious, I finally got a reply about the bug in the .NET Framework. I was told "Fixes are not automatically moving from .NET Core to .NET Framework. Please read https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-the-future-of-net/ for more details." I interpret that as "will not fix".